# Why are my buttons not invoking functions in html?

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

beginner here, I'm trying to make a display with buttons that could display additional information. I went about attempting this by having the information be set to display: none; and then setting them to display: inline; by invoking functions with a button.

However, it seems my buttons are not able to invoke the needed functions since even after attempting to console log the functions, they don't respond.

Here's the code all braces ie. {{}} are anki tags:

```
<style>
.card {
  font-family: Comic Sans MS; //Kid font
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

li {
    text-align:left;
    display:none;

}

button{
    display:block;
    width:28%;
    padding:auto;
    margin:auto;
}

.mono{ 
    font-family:"Courier New";
    font-size: 1.18em; 

    font-weight:bold;


    width:50%;
    margin: auto;
}


.etymology {
    margin:auto;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    display:none;

}

.info{

    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    display:none;


}
</style>

{{FrontSide}} // all tags with braces are anki tags

<hr id=answer>

<h2>{{def}}</h2>

<button onlclick="synonyms()"> Common Syn.</button>

<ul>
    <li>{{c1}}, </li><li>{{c2}}, </li><li>{{c3}}, </li><li>{{c4}}, </li><li>{{c5}}</li>
</ul>


<div class="mono"> 

    <div class="smol_details">

        <div class="etymology">{{etymology}}<br> "{{source_language}}"</div> 
        <button onlclick="etymology()">Language info </button>

        <div class="info">{{usage_cat}} {{recognition}} {{book}} <br>{{commentary}}</div>
        <button onlclick="data()"> data data</button>

    </div>

</div>


<script>
    function synonyms() {
    document.querySelectorAll("li").style.display = "inline";
    
    console.log("cliced");
} 

    function etymology() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".etymology").style.display = "inline";
console.log("cliced");
} 

    function data() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".info").style.display = "inline";
console.log("cliced");
} 

</script>
```

I need to have the

, .etymology, and .data be visible when the buttons related to them are clicked. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled onclick
Change onlclick to onclick

Comment: Ahhh ... I'm an idiot, I'm soryy haha.

At least now I'm at least getting an error which is progress from last time.

I'm now getting a an error 

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'display')
```

Comment: Is it not possible to use quearySelector in conjunction with .style ?

Comment: When i try to access document.querySelectorAll(".etymology").style I get undefined

Comment: Nvm. I've figured it out. Turns out I shouldn't be using quearySelectorAll. Instead I should be using quearySelector. 

it works for the most part now except for the "li" Which I think I have to loop in order to work.

Thank you anyways. The mispelling went over my radar so at least I figured out now what was wrong